# Using [NotifyPropertyChangedFor()] source generator on ObservableCollection is not updating UI

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui, sourcegenerators

I would expect something like this to work:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Count))]
public ObservableCollection<TODO> todos = new();

public int Count => Todos.Count;
```

While the `Count` is getting updated at the ViewModel layer, the UI does not seem to update. I have also tried using the `OnTodosChanged` method generated by the Mvvm CommunityToolkit source generator but that is not getting fired as well. Note that I am expected the UI to update on invoking the `Add`, etc methods of `Todos`.

1. Why doesn't `[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Count))]` update the UI Count on `Add`ing to `Todos` collection? If this is not the way to do this, then what is?
2. Why doesn't `OnTodosChanged` get called on `Add`ition of elements to `Todos` collection?
3. Would the UI update for an operation like `Todos[0].IsCompleted = true`? If not, what is the way to handle this?

The reason I decided to post here was I could not find any relevant documentation (which is quite frustrating because I am thinking this might be something that is commonly done) nor any tutorial videos / sample apps leading me to question if this is the correct way to go about this. Help would be appreciated! - Thank you :^)

Comment: Your `todos` looks like a field, not a property. You need to make it an **immutable** property: collection properties should never be overwritable, especailly not `ObservableCollection<T>` (because that would break all the databinding references)

Comment: Are you using VS' XAML Binding Errors window as a guide?

Comment: @Dai I am on Visual Studio for Mac and does not like it supports XAML data binding diagnostics (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-data-binding-diagnostics?view=vs-2022).

Comment: Please make sure to only focus on a single problem per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing with the [MVVM Source Generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/overview) here:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Count))]
public ObservableCollection<TODO> todos = new();

public int Count => Todos.Count;
```

is equivalent to writing the following:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<TODO> _todos = new();
public ObservableCollection<TODO> Todos
{
    get => _todos;
    set
    {
        if(_todos == value) return;
        _todos = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Todos));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));
    }
}

public int Count => Todos.Count;
```

The `PropertyChanged` notification only occurs when the `Todos` *property* is changed, but **not** when the *content* of the `ObservableCollection<TODOS>` changes. Adding elements to the collection is not changing the property.

If you want to notify changes to the `Count` property when items are added to the `Todos` collection, then you need to subscribe to the collections's `CollectionChanged` event:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
public ObservableCollection<TODO> todos;

public int Count => Todos.Count;

public YouClassConstructor()
{
    Todos = new();
    Todos.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));
}
```

I've also written a small [blog series](https://blog.ewers-peters.de/series/mvvm-goodness) about the MVVM Source Generators, if you want to take a deeper dive into the topic.

Comment: Thank you - this makes sense. Just a question though - with the solution provided, looks like we'll need to mix and match  the source generated code vs vanilla code - is that the case or am I just reading this wrong?

Comment: This is the only way you can do it. The source generators work with properties, commands, and so on, but they don't have any control over what the class instances that are referenced by a property do. The source generators don't know anything about the collection having a `CollectionChanged` event. Note that the MVVM Community Toolkit's source generators don't provide a replacement for the regular (or vanilla) way of doing things, they're just providing a shortcut to reduce writing boilerplate code. Your situation is not boilerplate.

Comment: @Julian _"The source generators don't know anything about the collection having a CollectionChanged event."_ - Correct me if I'm wrong, but as SourceGenerators are based on Roslyn Analyzers, which exposes both the SyntaxTrees and Semantic Models of a compilation, source-generators _can_ generate output contingent on _anything_ in your codebase.

Comment: @Dai I'm specifically talking about the source generators of the MVVM Community Toolkit, which is the matter of the question and answer. As of writing, there is no generator that analyzes what type a property has to then expose access to events and properties of that specific type. While in theory this should be possible, such a source generator doesn't exist at the moment and I don't think it will be added to the MCT anytime soon as this isn't a straightforward thing to do.

Comment: @Julian Ah, good to know (as I'm about to start on a new MVVM project soon), thanks